# Get File Upload Time From Server

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

Is there a way, using urllib2 or something else, to check the time a file was uploaded to a URL? Or even the time the file on the server side was last modified?

At the moment I'm manually using `urllib2.urlopen()` to read data from a url address. The arguments for the address change each day. What I'd like to do is figure out when each file was first available, so that I can pick the best time for the job to automatically run overnight.

Comment: You need to elaborate more on what you need. How are the files stored? What do you mean "using urllib2" and how does that relate to the problem?

Comment: Check the `Last-Modified` header, if the server sends one (if not, then you're out of luck).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time is stored in the server which is usually sent to your browser as HTTP headers. You can access this in Javascript using document.lastModified property. Here's a solution in Python that reads headers and parses the information using regular expression and prints the result.

```
def get_upload_datetime(myurl):
    info = urllib2.urlopen(myurl).info() 
    datetime = re.search("Last-Modified: (.+)", str(info))
    if datetime:
        return datetime.groups()[0]
```

If you are also using contents of the webpage,use urlopen.info() and urlopen.read() on the same object *(actually read only once)* to avoid multiple fetches.

And if you want to do it manually, open webpage in the browser, open console (Ctrl+Shift+J) and type `javascript:alert(document.lastModified)`. It should present an alert box with last modified time.